# Как поменять классы у кнопок в Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так чтобы значения классов (*InactiveButton*, *АctiveButton*) у кнопок поменялись местами?

```
<button id="delButton" class="ActiveButton">Самовывоз</button>
<button id="delButton" class="InactiveButton">Доставка</button>
```

Сам пытался сделать нечто подобное, но не получилось

```
$('.InactveButton').click(function (){
    $(this).toggleClass('InactiveButton').toggleClass('ActiveButton');
    $('.ActiveBbutton').toggleClass('InactiveButton').toggleClass('ActiveButton');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо повесить событие на общий селектор данных кнопок (в нашем случае в качестве селектора выступит тег `button`). При клике на кнопку меняем классы у всех с `InactiveButton` на `ActiveButton`. После у текущей кнопки уже меняем классы обратно.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('button').removeClass('ActiveButton').addClass('InactiveButton'); //можно и toggleClass использовать 
 $(this).toggleClass('ActiveButton').toggleClass('InactiveButton')
});
```

```css
.InactiveButton {
opacity: 0.5;
}
.ActiveButton {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="delButton-1" class="ActiveButton">Самовывоз</button>
<button id="delButton-2" class="InactiveButton">Доставка</button>
```

P.S. И не забываем, что идентификаторы на странице должны быть разными. Повторяющихся быть не должно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне именно нужно, чтобы функция отрабатывала при нажатии на кнопку класса InactiveButton. Вообще мне нужно сделать что-то наподобие переключателя, где InnactiveButton неактивная кнопка, при нажатии на которую эта кнопка становится активной, а кнопка класса ActiveButton наоборот становится неактивной

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё одно решение:

```
<button id="qqq" class="qqq">Самовывоз</button>
<button id="www" class="www ActiveButton">Доставка</button>
```

```
 $('#qqq').click(function() {
                            if ($('#qqq').hasClass('ActiveButton') == false)
                            {
                                $( "#qqq" ).addClass( 'ActiveButton' );
                                $( "#www" ).removeClass( 'ActiveButton' );
                            }
                        })

                        $('#www').click(function() {
                            if ($('#www').hasClass('ActiveButton') == false)
                            {
                                $( "#www" ).addClass( 'ActiveButton' );
                                $( "#qqq" ).removeClass( 'ActiveButton' );
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит назначать одинаковый id элементам.
Возможно в Вашем случае не обязательно менять местами классы. Можно изначально назначить один общий класс для кнопок (аналог inactive), и просто добавлять/удалять класс `active`, который будет применять необходимый стиль.
Пример ниже.

```js
$('.delBtn').click(function (){
    $('.delBtn.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

```css
.delBtn {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.delBtn.active {
  opacity: 1;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="delBtn">Самовывоз</button>
<button class="delBtn active">Доставка</button>
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое